# Node.js module.exports multiple classes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 2 files called a.js and b.js, both contain classes. I'm trying to import and create a new instance of class B inside class A using the following code

a.js

```
module.exports.A = A;
var classB = require('./b.js').B;
A.protoype.Init = function(){
this.B = new classB();
```

b.js

```
module.exports.B = B;
function B(a_class)
{
  this.a = a_class;
}
```

I receive the following error

> TypeError: undefined is not a function at this.B = new class B();

Comment: In b.js, is `B` defined to a function? If that's your whole b.js file then `B` is `undefined` and so will `classB` in a.js file.

Comment: The problem is with your definition of `B` so you need to show thatpart of `b.js`.

Comment: Looks like it should work as it is, unless there is other code in `b.js` that somehow modifies the value of `B`.

Comment: Your brackets don't match in `a.js`, which makes me think that the code that makes this not work as expected is missing.  Try coming up with a minimal example that exhibits the issue, and add that to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined your A class in your a.js file:

a.js - I added a constructor function for your A class:

```
module.exports.A = A;
var classB = require('./b.js').B;

function A() {}

A.protoype.Init = function(){
    this.B = new classB();
}
```